# How to edit a java map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a simple question about a java map.Suppose I have  a map that has a key and value already set. How do I change the value of that key; what method would I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call a normal put -- it will replace the existing value for the key.  If you need to access the old value for that key, the put method returns it.

See [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're referring to the `java.util.Map` class? You can simply use `put()` - it will replace an existing value if that key has already been set.